Hard drive access denied
after installing Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS Noble Numbat, on my PC (16 × AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core Processor, GeForce GTX 1080, 31.3 Gio RAM) I get an error message, when I click on one of my internal hard drives on Dolphin:
The requested operation failed: 
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/rc/INFOGRAPHIES: 
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, 
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Despite several searches on the net, I haven't managed to find an answer to this problem. As a newcomer to Linux, without any expertise on the subject, I come to you in the hope of finding a solution...
Thanks in advance.

Is the hard drive formatted NTFS or some other format type? add this information into your question above by either clicking on this link or by clicking on the Edit button below the question.

This question is similar to: Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For specific advice; you've told us what you're using (thank you) but have given no clues as to the actual drive partition sda1 you're trying to mount; ie. file-system involved; if you've performed a file-system check on it to check for any errors & correct; if windows is involved & the file-system is left unclean (windows hibernate/fastboot were involved etc). I'd start by checking unstated file-system for errors; as if detected & fixed, the problem you have no won't exist (ie. it'll mount correctly), but there could be other issues too.

First thing to know is what format the disk uses. If it is a windows disk (ntfs), a mac disk (hfs, hfs+) or linux disk (ext4). vfat, Exfat is supported on all 3 systems.
for ntfs install:  sudo apt install ntfs-3g-dev
for exfat install: sudo apt install exfat-fuse
Find the disk:
sudo fdisk -l  (or) sudo lshw -short -C disk

Make a mountpoint at wil: I'll use the user desktop!!
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/Mountpoint

mount disk:
sudo mount -t ntfs  /dev/sda* ~/Desktop/Mountpoint
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sda* ~/Desktop/Mountpoint

